# Best approach to assemble uploaded file chunks using spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, plupload

I am using spring-boot for my back end and plupload at front end to upload chunked files.

I have a post rest endpoint, which accepts a Multipart file in the form-data.

The scenario is, based on the chunk size plupload will create n chunks and will call the post endpoint n times, with each time the subsequent chunks.

Now i need to assemble these chunks at the server end, the endpoint might get requests from many clients simultaneously, so the problem is 
1) Need to identify all the requests from same client.
2) Need to identify chunk0,chunk1...., chunk1 of same file
3) Need to wait until all chunks get uploaded before reassembling.

My constraint is, i wont get large local storage space to store those chunks as temp files in a folder path, and maintain a hashmap for each file through some unique identifier and reassemble once the nth file reaches.

If someone has got some solution around this problem, please provide an answer or some git hub links would help.

Comment: Either you have store it in memory/local storage or if you have constraints go with some storage.Detailed explanaton : https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: The storage here you mean a db ?

Comment: How would you suggest to handle uniqueness of a file, among many uploaders or is there any framework that enables such a feature ?

Comment: Yes a db, for uniqueness, create a key with filename or other file upload params like username+file,etc.

Comment: Which DB would you suggest here for quick store and retrieval, since performance would be bottleneck, would you suggest some nosql datastores ??

Comment: As you can see on spring guide page,they are suggesting GridFS,but I personally haven't used it.Any nosql store would suffice as key-value storage and retrieval is fast enough in them.I have used Hbase with underlying HDFS storage for the same,since It was already in our stack.

Comment: Could you pls post some sample, if you could on handling temp store on a db !!

Comment: Any updates on this.